# How to create a user defined exception in Ruby from user input

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a user defined error where, if the user enters their first name only, it raises an error and tells the user to try again or, if they enter a numeral, it will raise an error.

This is my code but when I run it it outputs "Enter your first and last name" then it rescues it no matter if I enter a full name. It still says "Sorry I didn't quite catch that." then concatenates it:

```
class MyNewException < Exception
  attr_reader :first, :last

  def initialize(first)
    @first = first
  end
end

print "Enter your first and last name: "

begin

first = gets.chomp
last = gets.chomp

#prompt the user to enter first and last name
rescue MyNewException
  puts "Sorry I didn't quite catch that. Try again."
  gets
else
  puts "Hello, " + first + last + "!"
end
```

Comment: It worked for me when I copied your code into irb.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gets` will grab everything you type before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So `first` actually includes the first and last name that you are entering, and then `last` is empty. It looks like they are being concatenated, but all the text is in `first`. If you enter your first name, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then enter your second name, then it should output both names.

The error is not being raised. You need to add something like this if you want to raise the error when last is blank:

```
last = gets.chomp
if last == ""
  raise MyNewException, first
end
```